# jQuery: Attach additional functions to existing event handler using $.delegate

Tags: jquery, delegates

My organization has a standard jQuery/JavaScript framework shared by multiple applications. In this framework, we set a basic standard for jQuery's datepicker functionality that can be consumed with dynamically-loaded elements:

```
$(document).delegate("input.calendar", "click, focus", function() { 
    myAppDatepicker = $(this).datepicker({
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    });
});
```

I'd like to do something like:

```
$(document).delegate("input.calendar", "click, focus", function() { 
    myAppDatepicker.datepicker("option", "maxDate", 0);
});
```

to add additional options to the datepicker. This method doesn't work -- I'd guess because the second delegate listener is replacing the handlers from the first listener where I want to append the additional options.

Currently, this throws a "myAppDatepicker is not defined" error.

I can do this via $.bind in Firebug, but it doesn't work against dynamically loaded elements. Any ideas on how to make this work against elements that don't exist in the DOM at load time?

Answer (score 0):

Changing:

```
$(document).delegate("input.calendar", "click, focus", function() { 
    **myAppDatepicker**.datepicker("option", "maxDate", 0);
});
```

to

```
$(document).delegate("input.calendar", "click, focus", function() { 
    **$(this)**.datepicker("option", "maxDate", 0);
});
```

appends the additional options as expected.